# CMS without Back end or database

Tags: html, content-management-system

Will i be able to use wordpress CMS without a Database or back end of a website, cause the website's purpose is just for advertising or displaying the company's contents

Comment: Odd that this question was asked twice within a minute of each other. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326159/cms-without-webhost

Comment: Why do you need a CMS ?

Comment: to freely edit the content of the website

Comment: @DarylTing see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether using a CMS without a database is worthwhile for your own project depends on a range of different factors. The advantages, as well as the typical problems of non-database CMSs, are summarised here:

- CMSs without databases are usually quite plain and are limited to the most essential features and therefore users don’t need much of a familiarisation period.
- Web project backups are easily taken care of since no complex database backup is required, so data just needs to be downloaded from the webspace.
- The direct transfer of information without having to detour over a database means there is a shorter loading time and faster access to the web project.
- A small CMS system generally doesn’t require much webspace and doesn’t demand any special requirements from the hardware.

**As well as numerous advantages there are also some disadvantages of CMSs without databases:**

- The possibilities of non-database CMS systems are limited, which is why the systems are best suited to smaller projects with minimal static sites. Dynamic websites cannot be created without databases.
- Since simple CMS systems usually only offer small communities, the user is often left alone with questions and problems and has to sort through documents to work it out themselves.
- The often unavailable codes and minimal distribution of CMS software can mean that the simple CMS becomes boring for the user since there is less chance of development.
- Not working in a structured and neat manner on a simple content management system could make it difficult to find specific content again.

**What kind of projects are simple CMS systems suitable for?**

With the list of pros and cons of non-database content management systems you could assume that this software solution isn’t suitable for managing content of every project. The advantages of non-database systems only really materialise in small web projects. Deciding to pass on using a database has a positive impact on the performance, but a negative one on the structure of bigger web projects. Also the use of dynamic web pages with a CMS without database isn’t possible. Users that are planning a web project with constant updating and heavy interaction with website visitors, shouldn’t opt for a simple CMS system without a database. The same applies for owners of bigger websites whose complex structures prove too much for a non-database content management system.

On the other hand, there are projects that benefit from using a CMS without a database: small websites, which are built using simple structures and don’t have a lot of pages, can be quickly created with this CMS and will impress visitors with fast access to the information they are looking for. These CMS systems are best suited to small businesses or freelancers who want to introduce their range of services. Running a blog will also work on a small CMS system.

A considerable advantage of such a lean system is that no hardware is needed to operate the database server, so the user saves money and also doesn’t need any laborious backups. Less experienced users can benefit from a clear structure and easy start.

**A CMS without database is suitable for:**

- Small and medium-sized homepages
- Operating blogs
- Introducing a range of services (businesses, freelancers)

**Simple CMS systems are not suitable for:**

- Online stores
- News sites
- Online services
- Websites with lots of multimedia content

**Recommendation of a simple CMS:**

**GetSimple CMS**

The cleverly-chosen motto of the non-database GetSimple CMS is “GetSimple has everything you need, and nothing you don’t”. The GPLv3 licensed open source software GetSimple CMS is characterised by its minimalistic structure, which offers the essentials and can be expanded with plugins. Since the software code is freely accessible and can be modified, the user can adapt the CMS system to suit needs. Data is saved on the webspace in XML format. Further information on this CMS includes:

- 5-minute installation
- Intuitive user interface
- Undo function for all modifications
- Creation of numerous backend accounts
- First class documentation (Wiki)
- Very active community
- HTML5 template

Comment: thank you sir, so i still can use cms without database, this is just a small website for posting updates of a company that's why it does not have any database, im only managing contents, and has no transaction to anyone visiting the page

Comment: @DarylTing Plenty of CMS out there that do not use a "database". getSimple is one that I have previously used and it uses xml to store data

Comment: one more thing sir, cause i got my own website files, will i be able to use this cms on it

Comment: Yes! http://get-simple.info/wiki/themes:creation http://get-simple.info/wiki/themes:tutorial

Answer (score 0):

no you will not be able to use wordpress without a database, the database stores everything

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with Bodyless CMS, it dosen't require any database, backend. A Front-end only CMS build with angular 6. You can check this out in github (https://github.com/chaitanya11/BodylessCMS). Currently it supports deployment only in AWS. It has inbuilt web building framework (GrapesJs) to design web page. You can check this article (https://medium.com/@chaitanya.garikipati123/bodylesscms-e2a83a841cd).